# How to delete model - IBM Watson

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson, naivebayes

I'm trying out Watson Studio model for Naive Bayes model.In my app I need to delete old deployment model and add new one.
Is it possible to delete such model using the python API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to keep the same deployment endpoint url and credentials when you replace a model, I believe you will need to use the REST API directly ([docs](https://watson-ml-api.mybluemix.net/#!/Published32Models/patch_v3_wml_instances_instance_id_published_models_published_model_id)):

[image]

---

**Update**

This is now available in the python library:

[image]

Comment: It is a good way to solve that, but i probably use watson-machine-learnig-client to delete old deployment and model and create new one

Comment: I added a feature request - https://ibmwatsondataplatform.ideas.aha.io/ideas/IBMWDP-I-376.  Please vote :)

Comment: @ProgShiled you can deploy a new model using python.  I've updated my answer with the API methods for this.